# Apache + url rewriting

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I'm having a Apache problem of "Too many redirects on my website". I've been trying to fix it in different ways but I can't find a solution.

```
referer = http://www.mysite.com/
lang = en | es | fr
page = page1, page2, page3

eg: referer/lang, referer/lang/
eg: referer/lang/page, referer/lang/page/
eg: referer/lang/something/apage, referer/lang/something/apage/
```

Here are my rules:

```
//Rewrite my ajax page location to avoid problems due to /lang/
RewriteRule ^(?:en|es|fr)/{0,1}ajax/ajax.php$ ajax/ajax.php [L]

//Rewrite /lang without page
RewriteRule ^(en|es|fr)/{0,1}$ /?lang=$1 [L]

//Rewrite referer/lang/something/unepage
RewriteRule ^(en|es|fr)/(somethinges|somethingfr|somethingen)/(apage1|apage2|apage3)$ /?lang=$1&page=$3 [L]

//Rewrite /lang/page
RewriteRule ^(en|es|fr)/(.*)$ /?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

I tried to repalce /?... by %{HTTP_REFERER}?...

Comment: Where are your rules, in an htaccess file? Where is the htaccess file? Can you give an example of a URL that is causing the "too many redirects"?

Comment: My rules are at the end of the htaccess file I have a couple of things before for cache, avoiding links on my images. The htaccess file is at the root of the website in the www/

I don't really have an idea where the problem occures since the website is down because of that for the time the DNS re initialize.

Oh, and, unfortunatly, I don't have access to the httpd.conf and apache logs -_-

Comment: When I add these rules to a blank htaccess file in my document root, and go to `/en/ajax/ajax.php`, I get `/ajax/ajax.php`, if I go to `/es`, I get `/?lang=es`, if I go to `/fr/somethingfr/apage1` I get `/?lang=fr&page=apage1`, and if I go to `/en/something`, I get `/?lang=en&page=something`, so it looks like everything works to me.

Comment: So does it for me, but for some reasons, there's a "too many redirects" somewhere which resulted in the website to be down :/ I'll try to get the Apache logs from my provider but I'm not sure they will send them to me... Anyway, thanks for your concern.